# Double percent sign in css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having an issue in CSS where my div is only appearing when I have 2 percent signs.

If I have:

```
<div class="col-md-8" style="display:inline-block;">
  <audio style="width:50%%" controls="controls">
    Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
    <source src="music_mix.mp3" type="audio/mp3"> 
  </audio>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4"style="display:inline-block;">Speed:
  <div class="slidecontainer" style="width:50%%"> 
    <input style="border-radius: 5px;" type="range" min="1" max="20" value="14" ng-change="updateValue()"   ng-model="trueSpeed" class="slider" ></div> {{speed}} 
  </div>
</div>
```

This works fine (note the 50%% on line 2).

But if I remove the extra % sign, the audio tag dispers entirely.

```
<div class="col-md-8" style="display:inline-block;">
  <audio style="width:50%%" controls="controls">
    Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
    <source src="music_mix.mp3" type="audio/mp3"> 
  </audio>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4"style="display:inline-block;">Speed:
  <div class="slidecontainer" style="width:50%"> 
    <input style="border-radius: 5px;" type="range" min="1" max="20" value="14" ng-change="updateValue()"   ng-model="trueSpeed" class="slider" ></div> {{speed}} 
  </div>
</div>
```

**This obviously doesn't seem right**, and I did not intend to type 2 in the first place. What could be causing this?

[Js fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/z5qLendy/)

Comment: why not wrapping it with a div like so `<div style="width:50%">
          <audio  controls="controls">
      Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
      <source src="music_mix.mp3" type="audio/mp3"> 
    </audio>
        </div>`? br

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `width:50%%` is invalid, it means `<audio>` will take the user agent style i.e. `width:300px` (See in the inspect) in chrome. Thats why its working.

The `width:50%` is valid, but in your case width is not working because your parent has `0` width and `0%` of `0` is also `0`.

Try to give width in `px` or give width to your parent.

***Stack Snippet***

```html
<div class="col-md-8" style="display:inline-block;">
  <audio style="width:100px" controls="controls">
    Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
    <source src="music_mix.mp3" type="audio/mp3"> 
  </audio>
</div>
```